# AttributeError: module 'tweepy' has no attribute 'OAuthHandler' when creating twitter bot

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

```
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

print(api.verify_credentials().screen_name)
```

I was trying to create my own Twitter bot, but it keeps showing errors that there is no attribute in tweepy called OAuthHandler. I've done quoting all my keys and tried "from tweepy.auth import OAuthHandler" but never worked.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried using tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler?

According to the Tweepy documentation OAuthHandler was deprecated since version 4.5. [Source](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/authentication.html#tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler)